# beginner in OOP in c++, assignment issues

Tags: c++, oop, declaration, definition

This is my first major assignment in OOP in C++.
for my header I have been given the following class definition:

```
using namespace std;

class Fraction
{
  public:
    Fraction(void);
    Fraction(int aN, int aD);
    int getNumerator();
    int getDenominator();
    Fraction adder(Fraction aF);
    ~ Fraction(void);
}
```

The assignment says that the adder function is supposed to work in a way where the current object is the first operand and the parameter of the function is the second operand. ex. If the object is 1/6 and the parameter is 1/3 then adder is supposed to give 3/6.

My questions are following:

a) Both `getNumerator()` and `getDenominator()` are set to return an integer, but I have no idea what adder(Fraction aF) is supposed to return. It says that it is supposed to return an instance of the class `Fraction`. It can't be a integer even though my product is supposed to produce two, if we were to go by the parameters set in the constructor.

for instance this is the cpp i have built so far:

```
#include "fraction.h"
#include <string>

Fraction::Fraction()
{
}

Fraction::Fraction(int aN, int aD) {
    numerator = aN;
    denominator= aD;
}

int Fraction::getNumerator() {
    return numerator;
}

int Fraction::getDenominator() {
    return denominator;
}

Fraction Fractiom::adder(Fraction aF) {
    aF = 1/3?      
    return ??
}

Fraction::~Fraction()
{
}
```

The issue isn't the arithmetic. I can figure those out. I just don't know what this function adder can return. I need the most simple example so just about anything compiles, just so I know which size I am dealing with (an integer, a single string etc.)

Then if we look at the source i have made.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fraction.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    Fraction f1(1, 6);
    cout << f1.getNumerator() << "/" << f1.getDenominator() << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The first example just shows how I use `getNumerator()` and `getDenominautor() to produce a random`Fraction`.

b) I assume I can write `f1.adder(aF)` to produce my product when I get the arithmetic in the cpp right, or is that assumption wrong?

Comment: My main dosen't include the adder function, besides the issue is i can't equate aF with and int, since it is a Fraction object. i Just get no operator¨=¨ matches these operands.

Comment: 1) I meant it isnt part of the main yet. 2) i think i misunderstand your point then. It  seems like your saying that i can change the integrals in f1 to get a new fraction, but i know that. I dont know how to initilaize my aF or how to make my adder, return an fraction object

Comment: You don't need to return `aF`, instead initialize another `Fraction` like `Fraction result(..., ...); return result;` or do it directly in the return statement as madmax shows.

Answer (score 3):

a) It's clear that your method Fraction::adder must return another Fraction object like this:

```
...
return Fraction(resultingNumeratorHere, resultingDenominatorHere);
```

b) Definitely. You have to implement the arithmetics in the cpp

Comment: I tried to write return Fraction( getnumerator(),getdenominator)

Comment: I tried to write return Fraction( getnumerator(),getdenominator), just to get  a random fraction back without actually adding anything. The issue is when i go to my main, i try to type something like cout << b1.adder()<<endl;. but it says to few arguments in my function call. I need to add something inside adder() i suppose, but what?

Comment: In this case you're returning the exact copy of your object.

You must use something like this:

    Fraction Fraction::adder(Fraction af) {
   return Fraction(numerator * af.denominator + denominator * af.numerator, denominator * af.denominator);
    }

Comment: Oops, missing format.

Your call must be:
Fraction f1(1, 6);
Fraction f2(1, 3);

Fraction result = f2.adder(f1);

Comment: You cannot pass Fraction instance to the cout directly now.
Try to overload the << operator or use your getters.

cout << result.getNumerator() << "/" << result.getDenominator();

Comment: i will look at that but i can't answer right away, as i will be testing. Thx a hundred times.

Comment: It seems to be working, thx again for the help, as you might have noticed i am brand new to c++. This did actually make some pieces fall in place for me as i was writing it myself.